# Adding a schema to .xml file

Tags: xml, excel

I have made reference to some codes in the Internet to convert an Excel file into an .xml file.  As far as I understand, the codes first extract the information from the Excel file and convert it to a string, and then write the string into an .xml file.

The codes used to write the string to the xml file are like this:

```
Sub sWriteFile(strXML As String, strFullFileName As String)

    Dim intFileNum As String

    intFileNum = FreeFile
    Open strFullFileName For Output As #intFileNum
    Print #intFileNum, strXML
    Close #intFileNum

End Sub
```

After running the codes, I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FATCA_OECD>
    <MessageSpec>
        <Tag2a>XXX</Tag2a>
        <Tag2b>XXX</Tag2b>
    </MessageSpec>
</FATCA_OECD>
```

I want the `FATCA_OECD` tag to become:

```
<ftc:FATCA_OECD xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1 FatcaXML_v1.1.xsd" version="1.1" xmlns="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v1" xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

and I also want the `MessageSpec` tag to become:

```
<ftc:MessageSpec>
```

I tried to type all the namespace information as strings in appropriate places of the codes.  However, whenever I add in special characters like colons, the .xml file generated from the codes appear to be a blank one.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Your code `sWriteFile` only writes a string into a file. How `strXML` is generated? That code would be of interest.

Comment: The codes I used had been found here (thanks to Raymond Pang and KevinGreiner): https://github.com/greinerk/stuff/blob/master/xls2xml/XLS%202%20XML%20-%20blank.xls

Comment: Sorry, I'm out here. `MSXML2.DOMDocument` exists, so no need reinventing the wheel and concatenate XML together from strings. Ask those who have programmed this.